# I have Javascript code that doesn't allow HTML property (text specifically) to change in the loop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

I have a code in mind when if a website first open, a certain text would go in a loop where it display the words that are in a list. When I attempt to run the code, the console described that the "text[num]" has an error and, therefore, couldn't run the code. This is the following code:

```
var num = 0;




var texts = [
"1 Element",
"2 Element",
"3 Element",
"4 Element",
"5 Element"
];




window.onload = function() {
changingTitleLoop();
}




function changingTitleLoop(){
setTimeout(function() {
  changeText();
  // Call the loop function again to create an endless loop
  num++;
  changingTitleLoop();
}, 3000);
}




function changeText(){
if(num >= texts.length){
  num = 0;
} else {
  var something = document.getElementById("changingText");
  something.textContent = texts[num];
}
}
```

I tried changing the tag "textContent" to "innerHTML", however it didnt fix the problem. Is there something I'm missing in the code? any mistakes?

Comment: The code is running here with a bug but not an error. Maybe it's something else than the code.

Comment: Please show the exact error that you are seeing. I cannot currently reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** I was reviewing the code when I realized that I needed to specify the specific "array" or "position" of the essential element since I was using getElementByIDName(). In this case, I decided to use getElementsByClassName() to see if there were much of differences.

As it turns out, I would need to use *either* document.getElementsByClassName("changingText")[0] **or** replace document.getElementsByClassName("changingText") with document.querySelector(".changingText"). As a result, the properties of  are found and run as JavaScript was able to change their textContent.

The code works as followed:

```
var num = 0;


var texts = [
"1 Element",
"2 Element",
"3 Element",
"4 Element",
"5 Element"
];


window.onload = function() {
changingTitleLoop();
}


function changingTitleLoop(){
setTimeout(function() {
  changeText();
  // Call the loop function again to create an endless loop
  num++;
  changingTitleLoop();}, 2000);

}


function changeText(){
if(num >= texts.length){
  num = 0;
} else {
  var element = document.querySelector(".changingText");
element.textContent = texts[num];
}
}
```

After checking the property of the element  figuring if there were CSS properties that may or may not affect JavaScript, it appears that the following HTML is still valid even with other Classes and Id tagged.

```
<h1 class="class1 changingText" id="id1">???</h1>
```